# Irrational factor in expression of trigonometric function: How many cycles?

Tags: trigonometry

I was discussing with someone I was teaching about how to understand $\sin(ax)$ on the interval $\left[ 0 , 2 \pi \right]$. Now, if we have $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, it's easy. We can write $a=\frac{p}{q}$ and then from there we can interpret that we swift through $\frac{p}{q}$ cycles in the interval $2\pi$.

So, for example, if $q=1$ and $p=3$, we'd go through three cycles of every value of sine.

Now, then I was asked , what about if we have irrational numbers... like $\sin(\pi x)$ how many cycles does that make in $0, 2 \pi$.

I can't seem to answer this. I am guessing, that answering this would do something with greatest integer function... but I can't pin it down.